# Invalid Date on moment.js

Tags: momentjs

**Invalid Date when trying to format date using moment JS**

I got invalid date when I tried to format this date `31/12/2012`to `moment(data).format('ll')` and i get a invalid date return.

Comment: Please add code and explain what you get as response

Comment: $data = new Date('31/12/2012);
and i was trying to do it. like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) intead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) since your input is neither in ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 format.

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

**Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

> 

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a live sample:

```js
var data = '31/12/2012'
console.log( moment(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('ll') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```